# force close when trying to start new intent

Tags: android

I want to start this activity,
but I've no idea why I couldn't start in now!!
when previously,
I'm able to start the activity..
I don't know what is wrong with my code, can someone help me out?
Thanks you

```
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.summary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.example.fuellogproject.summary.onCreate(summary.java:107)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-29 21:20:48.431: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    ... 11 more
```

my code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);

        monthDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.month);
        avgPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultFC);


            // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using
            // the DbHelper class
            AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

            // Then we need to get a readable database
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

            // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do
            // it for us
            // (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
            // selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
            Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
                    AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null);
            // Above given query, read all the columns and fields of the table

            startManagingCursor(cursor);

            // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will
            // not miss any by looping through a while loop
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // In one loop, cursor read one undergraduate all details
                // Assume, we also need to see all the details of each and every
                // undergraduate
                // What we have to do is in each loop, read all the values, pass
                // them to the POJO class
                // and create a ArrayList of undergraduates
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ROWID));

             final String date = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE));
            String price = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE));
                String pump = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL));
                String cost = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST));
                String odm = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM));
                String preodm = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PREODM));
                String fcon = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON));


                // If you don't close the database, you will get an error
            sqliteDatabase.close();
                Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + date);



        monthDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });





doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



if (monthDate.getText().toString().equals(date.subSequence(3,9).toString()))

                {   
     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),about.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    Log.d("ELSEMONTHDATE","date : "+ monthDate.getText().toString());
    Log.d("ELSEBUNDLEDATE","date : "+ (date.subSequence(3,9).toString()));


                }
                else 
                {
                     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),about.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("ELSEMONTHDATE","date : "+ monthDate.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("ELSEBUNDLEDATE","date : "+ (date.subSequence(3,9).toString()));
                }






            }
        });
}

    }
```

Comment: what is line 107 `summary.java`

Comment: I think you r calling same class in if - else condition...

Comment: doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: @Chloe did you try the suggestion in my post!. does it work

Answer (score 2):

You say line 107 is

```
 doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

You have not initialize `doneButton` any where

```
doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your buttonid);
```

Your `doneButton` is null. You need to make sure you initialize `doneButton` properly.